# Although i insert different string, str.format print same string

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to print different variable in one line with specific alignment. However, str.format print same string.

> Here is the code what i did and output

```
>>> print("{0:^20} {0:^20} {0:^40}\n".format('chkitem', 'Count', 'Coordinate'))
      chkitem              chkitem                        chkitem
```

I want to print

```
>>> print("{0:^20} {0:^20} {0:^40}\n".format('chkitem', 'Count', 'Coordinate'))
      chkitem              Count                        Coordinate
```

What is the problem?

Comment: print("{0:^20} {1:^20} {2:^40}\n".format('chkitem', 'Count', 'Coordinate'))

Comment: I highly recommend using a newer interpreter. In later versions of Python >= 3.6 you could do this with f-strings in a much friendlier way: `print(f"{'chkitem':^20} {'Count':^20} {'Coordinate':^40}\n")`

Comment: thank you for answering. i resolve the problem : ) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("{:^20} {:^20} {:^40}\n".format('chkitem', 'Count', 'Coordinate'))
```

The zeroes before the colons are specifying to use the zero-indexed format argument, if you omit them it will default to use the next format argument provided.

You can also specify `0:`, `1:`, `2:` and so on, but best practice is to only specify indexes if you want to print an argument more than once.

Answer (score 0):

{0:^20} - 0 is position of item in format arguments. You have to increase it.

```
print("{0:^20} {1:^20} {2:^40}\n".format('chkitem', 'Count', 'Coordinate'))
```